# cin>> not work with getline()

Tags: c++, getline, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string str;
  int age;
  cout << "Please enter age: ";
  cin>>age;
  cout << "Please enter full name: ";
  getline (cin,str);
  cout << "Thank you, " << str << ".\n";
}
```

Why function getline() not work when I using uperator >> to input integer ? What is better use for int input ?

Comment: define "not work". What happened that you didn't like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still have a newline in the stream after `cin>>age;`, which is giving you an empty string for the name.

You could solve it by just adding another `getline()` call after getting the age and throwing away the result. Another options is to call `cin.ignore(BIG_NUMBER, '\n');`, where `BIG_NUMBER` is MAX_INT or something.

Comment: Calling `getline()` twice can fix the issue, but the more efficient solution is to call `cin.ignore()` before the real `getline()`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Good idea. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Your `ignore` call needs a delimiter.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Oh, so it does. It defaults to EOF, not newline! This is why I just went with `getline()` in the first place. 8v)

Comment: `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Answer (score 1):

`getline()` won't work with an `int`, or any number for that matter. It is defined as such:

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );

istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

So, it takes in strings and `char*`'s; not digits.

Comment: `getline()` is being used for the name, not the integer. Take a closer look at the question.

Comment: and digits are also characters :)