# Reading a whole line from file in c++

Tags: c++, string, file

I am working on a program in c++ and I need to read an entire string of text from a file. The file contains an address on one of the lines like this "123 Easy Ave" this has to be pulled into one string or char. Here is the code I have:

The data file:

```
Matt Harrold
307C Meshel Hall
1000 .01 4
```

The data is made up of a first and last name which become CustomerName, the next line is the address which is to populate Address, Then three numbers: principle, InterestRate, Years.

The code:

```
float InterestRate = 0;
int Years = 0;
char Junk [20];
int FutureValue;
float OnePlusInterestRate;
int YearNumber;
int count = 0;
char CustomerName;
string Address;
int * YearsPointer;


       CustomerFile >> CustomerName
                >> Address
                >> Principle
                >> InterestRate
                >> Years;
```

Right now it only pulls in "103C" and stops at the space... Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: where are the rest of variables? why you just show us `Address`? Are all of the variables strings?

Comment: I don't see no "103C" in the file, do you mean "307C"?

Comment: I think it's a good homework question if it caused you to stop and think. Homework is kind of pointless if you already know how to do it all :) This is a common problem, so it's good to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: In response to feedback on my question, I have edited it to use the more appropriate `std::getline` instead of `std::istream::getline`. Both of these would suffice, but `std::getline` is better suited for `std::string`s and you don't have to worry about specifying the string size.

Use `std::getline()` from `<string>`.

There is a good reference and example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/.

You'll also need to be careful combining the extraction (`>>`) operator and `getline`. The top answer to this question ([cin>> not work with getline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332144/cin-not-work-with-getline)) explains briefly why they shouldn't be used together. In short, a call to `cin >>` (or whatever input stream you are using) leaves a newline in the stream, which is then picked up by `getline`, giving you an empty string. If you really want to use them together, you have to call `std::istream::ignore` in between the two calls.

Comment: Don't use them together, or don't find an article? I agree that they shouldn't be used, but I think it's a good idea to find an article to show the OP why they shouldn't be used together.

Comment: I meant, don't use `std::istream::getline`. It can only read up to a specified number of characters, or requires an infinite buffer, which is pretty ungood. For C++ programming this advice is just about as bad as  suggesting that a C programmer he should use `gets`.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: its not good only if you care about buffer size. if you care about buffer size, then yes, getline is not the function for the job. however if you don't care, its fine.

Comment: Fair enough. `std::getline` would be more ideal. In my first year at university, lecturers were pretty strict on what we could and couldn't use. The `<string>` library wasn't allowed until second year so that we were forced to use cstrings and `istream` methods. I skipped past the first line where he was using a `string`, so `std::getline` would be fine here. I'll update my answer. And at any rate, `std::getline` is easier to use in this case.

Comment: @Dani: you know what happens when you don't care about buffer size? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm Come on people, it's been what? 23 years? Programmers should know better by now.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Touché. Still, this is only a basic homework exercise. Not that I'm encouraging carelessness regarding buffer protection.

Comment: Ok, but when I change it to "cin.getline (Address, 20, '\n');" I end up with an error: error: no matching function for call to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::getline(std::string&, int, char)'

Comment: @TannerEwing: `std::getline(std::cin, Address)`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: maybe you like making your homework military standard safe, but most of us don't (I hope)

Comment: The problem is that `cin.getline` works with cstrings (`char[]` or `char*`), not `std::string` (from the `<string>` header).
Are you using `cin` here? It seems to me that you're reading from a file through the `CustomerFile` stream. Try `getline(CustomerFile, Address);` instead.

Comment: @Dani: I don't like passing off bad habits as ok. There's nothing "military standard safe" about preventing buffer overflows. It's actually "run-of-the-mill safe".

Comment: Ok, I changed it to std::getline(std::cin,  Address); and that seems to have fixed it... Thanks

Comment: Did that work okay? If you want to read from the CustomerFile, `std::cin` should be `CustomerFile`. I should also clarify: You only need to prepend `std::` to objects and functions from the standard library if you haven't put `using namespace std;` in your code. It's generally considered better style to avoid `using namespace std;`, but for simple homework tasks it's okay. If you have that, then you can eliminate the `std::` part. If your teacher/lecturer puts `using namespace std;`, then it's probably safer to do that for the time being.

Comment: Well I'm still having a heck of a time... Its 1am and I'm really mad... I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 3):

use `std::getline` from the `<string>` header.