# c++ get multiple lines

Tags: c++, input, console

I need a way to read the lines a user has pasted in the console. The user pastes it in this fashion:

1st line: n - number of lines except this one

2nd - nth: a string object

If I read it with cin, it reads the first line, exits the program, and the next lines is placed in the console input. With scanf I get similar results.

```
string s[100];

int N = 0;
scanf("%i", N);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
scanf("%s", s);
}
```

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: C++ streams (`cin` and `cout`) would be better to use to read strings

Comment: or even use `std::getline` function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351834/reading-a-whole-line-from-file-in-c

Comment: send **address** to `scanf` function - `scanf("%i", &N)` instead `scanf("%i", N)`

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if you used a `std::vector<std::string>` and use `std::getline` to extract the lines:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, line))
{
    if (!line.empty())
        lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getline() will do the trick for you. Try this:

```
string lines[100];

int number = 0;
cin >> number;

for (int idx = 0; idx != number; ++idx)
{
    getline(cin, lines[idx]);
}
```

Note that you cannot read more than 100 lines this way. If you want to dynamically allocate an array of lines of size n, you can use the new operator.